# How can I create a "category" Facet based on the parent page?

Tags: c#, episerver, episerver-find

I've got a hierarchy of pages such as

```
- Root
   - Category 1
        - Page 1
        - Page 2
   - Category 2
        - Page 3
```

I want to use Find to create a filter based on the Category page names. Here's what I've got so far, the bit I can't figure out is line 4

```
var result = _searchClient.Search()
                  .For(query)
                  .Filter(x => x.Ancestors().Match(rootPageLink.ID.ToString()))
                  .FilterFacet("Categories", x => x.ParentLink) // This doesn't work
                  .HistogramFacetFor(x => x.Price, 100)
                  .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize)
                  .GetContentResult();
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Filter() expects a Filter as the second argument but you can see what I'm trying to do.  It's roughly analagous to a SQL query like `GROUP BY ParentLink` and then display info like

> Category 1 (2 pages)
>   Category 2 (1 page)

Comment: A few questions. Can your child pages, i.e. Page 1, Page 2 have its own child pages? Are the pages of the same types?

Comment: @EricHerlitz The child pages don't themselves have children. Page 1,2 and 3 are all the same type, and the category pages are all of the same CategoryPage type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering

- your structure looks like that
- you are using UnifiedSearch

The ISearchContent interface of [UnifiedSearch](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/9/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Unified-search/) contains two useful properties in your scenario

- SearchSection
- SearchSubsection

Consider you have a path like this

`/returns/misc/yourstuff`

When looking at **Your Stuff** as a unified search hit the **SearchSection** would be ***Returns*** and the **SearchSubsection** would be ***Misc***

When looking at **Misc** hit the **SearchSection** would be ***Returns*** and the **SearchSubsection** would be `null` or not exist on the hit.

This means

- The **SearchSection** is **always** the first node below the root *unless your  result is a first level node*
- The **SearchSubsection** is **always** the first node below the **SearchSection** *unless your result is a first or second level node*

In your scenario the category pages would always be represented as SearchSections.

I'm unable to test this at the moment but something like this should get your started.

```
var result = _searchClient.Search()
                  .For(query)
                  .Filter(x => x.SearchSection.Exists())
                  .Filter(x => x.SearchSection.Match("yourcategorypage"))
                  .TermsFacetFor(x => x.SearchSection) // create facets if you like, fun stuff
                  //.FilterFacet("Categories", x => x.ParentLink) // This doesn't work
                  //.Filter(x => x.Ancestors().Match(rootPageLink.ID.ToString()))
                  .HistogramFacetFor(x => x.Price, 100)
                  .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize)
                  .GetContentResult();
```

**== Edit below==**

To customize the SearchSection using projections something similar to this should be implemented, assuming you want the SearchSection to always be the closest parent of type `CategoryPage`.

To implement in your Find Initialization

```
// use the appropriate datatype if PageData isn't applicable, i.e. ArticlePage
SearchClient.Instance.Conventions.ForInstancesOf<PageData>()
    .ExcludeField(x => x.SearchSection()) // remove the default mapping
    .IncludeField(x => x.SearchSection(true)); // add your own mapping
```

SearchSection extension method

```
public static class FieldExtensions
{
    public static string SearchSection<T>(this T page, bool overriding) where T : PageData
    {
        // we need to check if this page is a CategoryPage first
        if(page is CategoryPage) {
            return ""; // I assume nothing?
        }

        var ancestors = loader.GetAncestors(page.ContentLink).OfType<CategoryPage>();
        if(ancestors.any()){
            var closestCategoryPage = ancestors.First();
            return closestCategoryPage.whateverproperty;
        }

        // customs: nothing to declare
        return "";
    }
}
```

Or something like that, you'll figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for this Eric. I've just given it a go and section and subsection return the first two parts of the path, correct? In my question I was trying to simplify my example by putting my pages under the site root but in actuality the pages are 3 levels deep. Is it possible to get the _parent-page's path segment_?

Comment: Correct, that is what they are supposed to do. And it is possible to extend the UnifiedSearchHit but not a very clean approach. In such cases I'd recommend using projections. I'll write an example on this when I get a minute, but the idea is to project what you want onto the `SearchSection` or `SearchSubsection`

Comment: @GregB Did update the example with a custom field mapping which will be better than projections